# How do I change the default home page of my gitlab installation

Tags: gitlab

By default my gitlab homepage starts `www.mydomain.com/users/sign_in`. I would like to change this to show 'www.mydomain.com/public' instead. How do I configure this?

Comment: Sorry for not answering your question, but that would be a nice feature. You can add it in https://feedback.gitlab.com/

Comment: Here it is - http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/5286829-change-the-default-home-page-of-my-gitlab-installa

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Setting custom startpage for non-logged in users:

1. From **"Admin Area"** goto the gear on the left and choose **"Settings"**
2. Find parameter **"Home page URL"** and set it to `www.mygitlab.com/explore`.
   Optional set "After sign out path" to same url
3. Click save

Tested with version is 8.14.4 CE

Comment: Thank you! Ha ha! What a simple way to do it! And it took them three years to make it a feature. See the link in the comment to my question - I put a feedback and I was told this is an EE feature. I am hoping that GEO is moved to the CE some day :-)

Comment: Note as of Gitlab 13.6.1, that setting is under the "Sign-in restrictions" section in Settings->General

Answer (score 9):

*This answer was written while running Gitlab 6. Any instructions may be outdated.*

---

The feature request has been declined so you have to do it on your own and change the source code.

**Full tutorial here: [Kovah.me DevBlog](https://blog.kovah.de/en/customize-gitlab-installation/)**

**Short HowTo:**
Open `gitlab/app/views/layouts/devise.html.haml` and change what you want.

For example you could replace `%h1 GitLab` with your own logo. Use the image tag for it: `%img{:src => "/source/to/image.png"}`

But attention! You have to use spaces to indent all elements! And make a backup before running any upgrades.